# SWIG adds lines to delete variables that don't exist

Tags: python, c++, linux, swig

I have a C++ class that is able to output strings in normal ASCII or wide character format. I am using SWIG (version 3.0.5) to create the bindings for Python.  The bindings have to work under Windows (32-bit and 64-bit) and Linux (64-bit).  I have written a custom typemap to get strings from Python to my C++ class: / This typemap is used for getting strings from Python to the C++ class

```
%typemap(in) const myNamespace::myStringType&
{
    // Custom input conversion #7
    const char* pChars = "";
    PyObject* pyobj = $input;

    if(PyString_Check(pyobj))
    {
        pChars = PyString_AsString( pyobj );
        $1 = new myNamespace::myStringType( pChars );
    }
    else if (PyUnicode_Check( pyobj ))
    {
        PyObject* tmp = PyUnicode_AsUTF8String( pyobj );
        pChars = PyString_AsString( tmp );
        $1 = new myNamespace::myStringType( pChars );
    }
    else
    {
        std::string strTemp;
        int rrr = SWIG_ConvertPtr(pyobj, (void **) &strTemp, $descriptor(String), 0);
        if (!SWIG_IsOK(rrr))
            SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(rrr), "Expected a String "
        "in method '$symname', argument $argnum of type '$type'");
        $1 = new myNamespace::myStringType( strTemp );
    }
}
```

This typemap works fine for the 32-bit and 64-bit normal character builds, but a problem arises when I try to build for wide-character.  In the wide character builds, I need to include the following SWIG include files in my interface file:

```
%include "std_wiostream.i"
%include "std_wsstream.i"
```

When these include files are used with the above typemap we get spurious lines of code inserted into the wrapper like so:

```
if (SWIG_IsNewObj(res2)) delete arg2;
```

Here's an example of a complete wrapper function produced by SWIG:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_timeStampFromStr(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  myNamespace::myStringType *arg1 = 0 ;
  PyObject * obj0 = 0 ;
  slx::SlxU64 result;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,(char *)"O:timeStampFromStr",&obj0)) SWIG_fail;
  {
    // Custom input conversion #7
    const char* pChars = "";
    PyObject* pyobj = obj0;

    if(PyString_Check(pyobj))
    {
      pChars = PyString_AsString( pyobj );
      arg1 = new myNamespace::myStringType( pChars );
    }
    else if (PyUnicode_Check( pyobj ))
    {
      PyObject* tmp = PyUnicode_AsUTF8String( pyobj );
      pChars = PyString_AsString( tmp );
      arg1 = new myNamespace::myStringType( pChars );
    }
    else
    {
      std::string strTemp;
      int rrr = SWIG_ConvertPtr(pyobj, (void **) &strTemp, SWIGTYPE_String, 0);
      if (!SWIG_IsOK(rrr))
      SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(rrr), "Expected a String "
        "in method 'timeStampFromStr', argument 1 of type 'myNamespace::myStringType const &'");
      arg1 = new myNamespace::myStringType( strTemp );
    }
  }
  result = (slx::SlxU64)slx::timeStampFromStr((std::basic_string< char,std::char_traits< char >,std::allocator< char > > const &)*arg1);
  resultobj = SWIG_From_unsigned_SS_long_SS_long(static_cast< unsigned long long >(result));
  if (SWIG_IsNewObj(res2)) delete arg2;
  return resultobj;
fail:
  if (SWIG_IsNewObj(res2)) delete arg2;
  return NULL;
}
```

The code fails to compile because the res2 and arg2 variables are never defined in the wrapper code.

If I leave out the SWIG includes, the extra lines of code disappear but then I won't have the support for wide character iostream that I need.

Currently the work around is to manually delete these lines of code but obviously this will not work with automated builds in Windows and Makefiles in Linux.

Does anyone know why this happens?  I believe my typemap must have an error in it that is producing the extra lines of code, but again, this is ONLY happening when the SWIG include files for wide characters iostreams are included.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I experienced similar stuff in two cases. The first case was because multiple typemaps was applied. The other case was because, I was missing some %includes. Try to make a barebone example with only one typemap applied to a function with the given prototype and post a .i file with sources inline

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with string const &, it seems that Swig adds a wrong freearg statement from std_string.i. The workaround is to override the wrongly added delete:

```
%typemap(freearg) string const & {}
%typemap(freearg) const myNamespace::myStringType& {}
```